# CSS vertical align in box columns

Tags: css

I am trying to vertical align text in two columns. However, it will not do vertically due to the `float:left`; if I remove it the text will align vertically, but it messes up the columns. The text column in the first row will move to right.

The expected result is two rows.  First row has 2 columns, a vertically aligned text and the image.  Second row also has 2 columns, an image and a vertically aligned text.  In the mobile mode, it should be 4 rows; image, text, image, text.

The code is as follows:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.col-sm {
  width: 42%;
}

.col-la {
  width: 58%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.row {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.vtext {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.addpad {padding-left: 25px;}  
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-sm addpad pull-right">
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_oFaTRQXpeNg/TREVkIP-B0I/AAAAAAAAAG0/x10ih2-WZ8Q/s1600/001.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column col-la vtext">
    <b>First text column:</b>
    <ol>
      <li>It is on the left
        <li>with 3 bullet points
          <li>flowing to the left
    </ol>
    Shall become second row in mobile
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column col-sm">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Hoffl%C3%B6th(T%C3%B6Vo-Cl%C3%B6rath)-2(400x400).jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column col-la addpad vtext">
    <b>Second text column:</b>
    <ol>
      <li>flows to the right on desktop.
        <li>it has 3 bullet points
          <li>it will be the 4th rows on mobile
    </ol>
    <p>
      Text after bullets
  </div>
</div>
<b>Just some text not in the row.</b>
```

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not much clear to understand. Could you provide what is your expected output?

Comment: If you want to vertically center elements, you can use css `flex`. On you element add these  `dipalay: flex; align-items:center;` It will vertically align the child elements.  Refer https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If you are still not clear, try providing expected image/design of you code.

Comment: Its not exactly clear what it is that you expect. No one here can read your mind. You need to explain yourself better. If what your asking is, _"How to use a vertical aligning property on a floated element?"__ the answer is you don't. Floated elements are removed from the standard page layout, and the layout adjusts according the the floated property instead. thats why you have `float left` & `float right` properties, because the only thing the floated element knows for certain is the size of the DOM's width. Either switch to `flex`, `grid`, or align it using `margin`/`padding`.

Comment: @MdJunaidAlam I have updated the code to include the images so you have a better idea. I also added padding between the columns. On the desktop, the first row is vertically aligned text, then image. Second row is image and vertical aligned text. When on mobile, it is image, text, image, text.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to vertically align the text, using the code below, doesn't seem to work. That's because `display:table-cell` gets automatically disabled by the rendering engine because the element is floated.

```
.vtext {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

That's caused by this code:

```
.column {
  float: left;
}
```

which is floating all elements with `class="column"`, including the text you're trying to align. What you can do is remove that CSS, and reorder some elements in the HTML so the image appears on the right without needing to float it. We'll also need to individually apply CSS to the first row, so you can add `class="row first-row"` to it. We'll also add `class="img1"` to the image so we can change its size later (and `class="img2"` to the other one). This HTML for the first row should work:

```
<div class="row first-row">
    <div class="column col-la vtext">
        <b>First text column:</b>
        <ol>
        <li>It is on the left
        <li>with 3 bullet points
        <li>flowing to the left
        </ol>
        Shall become second row in mobile
    </div>
    <div class="column col-sm pull-right">
        <img class="img1" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_oFaTRQXpeNg/TREVkIP-B0I/AAAAAAAAAG0/x10ih2-WZ8Q/s1600/001.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we'll add a margin to the first row, so it lines up nicely with the other one:

```
.first-row {
    margin-left: 500px
}
```

The `500px` size of the margin probably won't be a problem on desktops, but it will be on phones, and so will the large images. So let's reduce the margin and image size for small screens by changing `@media` to:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;}
  .pull-right {
    position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  }
    .first-row {
        margin-left: 100px !important;
         }
    .img1 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
}
    .img2 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 290px;
        left: 10%;
    }
}
```

That code will position the image on the left. You can adjust the `left:` and `margin-left:` properties if you need to change its position.

If you want the images to be on top of the text, use this for `@media` instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;}
  .pull-right {
    position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
      top: 3%
  }
    .first-row {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-top: 100px; }
    .img1 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
}
    .img2 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 290px;
        left: 10%
    }
    .second-row {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

Your final code would be (with both images on the top on mobile):

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.col-sm {
    width: 42%;}
.col-la {
    width: 58%;}
.row {
    padding: 40px 0;
    display: table;
    clear: both;}
.vtext {display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;}
  .pull-right {
    position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
      top: 3%
  }
    .first-row {
        margin-left: 10px !important;
        margin-top: 100px; }
    .img1 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
}
    .img2 {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 290px;
        left: 10%
    }
    .second-row {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
}
.first-row {
    margin-left: 500px
}
.img2 {
    margin-right: 125px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row first-row">
    <div class="column col-la vtext">
        <b>First text column:</b>
        <ol>
        <li>It is on the left
        <li>with 3 bullet points
        <li>flowing to the left
        </ol>
        Shall become second row in mobile
    </div>
    <div class="column col-sm pull-right">
        <img class="img1" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_oFaTRQXpeNg/TREVkIP-B0I/AAAAAAAAAG0/x10ih2-WZ8Q/s1600/001.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row second-row">
    <div class="column col-sm">
    <img class="img2"src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Hoffl%C3%B6th(T%C3%B6Vo-Cl%C3%B6rath)-2(400x400).jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column col-la vtext">
    <b>Second text column:</b>
    <ol>
    <li>flows to the right on desktop.
    <li>it has 3 bullet points
    <li>it will be the 4th rows on mobile
    </ol>
    <p>
    Text after bullets
    </div>
</div>
<b>Just some text not in the row.</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work on mobile.  The image on the first row shall be on top on mobile.

Comment: @Jack, I just added information about changing the image positioning to my answer, including a way to make it go on the top.

Comment: The image should always be on the right.  Only when it is mobile then it goes to the top.

Comment: @Jack That is what my code does. If you're looking at it through the window that appears when you click "Run code snippet", the size of that window is too small, so it shows the CSS in `@media`. Can you try expanding the snippet then running it, or running the code on your browser in a fullscreen window? And if it doesn't work, can you check your screen width to see if it's less that 768px?

Comment: If you want the image to always be on the right, both on desktop and mobile, you can just remove `position: absolute;`, `top:3%;` and `left: 50px` from `@media`.

Comment: I have updated the code to include the images so you have a better idea. I also added padding between the columns.  On the desktop, the first row is vertically aligned text, then image.  Second row is image and vertical aligned text.  When on mobile, it is image, text, image, text.

Comment: @Jack I just updated my code one last time with two ways to position the images on mobile. Unfortunately I can't help much more than this, so try out both `@media` snippets, and you can play around with the positioning yourself if you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I just tried it but the second row photo overlaps the text in mobile :(

Comment: This actually doesn't work because it is playing with the image size.  If leaving it the same size, it really messes up the display.  We may have fixed one problem but create another one.   Sorry.